# sizeof struct less than 4 B is reported actual

Tags: c, struct, padding, sizeof

Am trying to understanding the struct padding. 
The below struct is padded:

```
struct s {
int j;
char c;
int i;
};
```

==> sizeof(struct s) = 12

But for this struct it is not padding. why?

```
struct s {
char c;
}
```

==> sizeof(struct s) = 1
OR

```
struct s {
short int i;
}
```

==> sizeof(struct s) = 2

Why the padding is not applicable for the above two structs?

Comment: Padding is traditionally done to put members on offsets that are good from a CPU perspective. If you only have a single member, the offset is always going to be zero, no need for padding.

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861582/why-is-padding-added-for-multiple-data-members-of-structures-and-not-for-single)

Answer (score 1):

Padding is done to keep members of the `struct` aligned, so that access is fast.(*) Consider what happens in an array of structs:

```
struct s {
    int i;
    char c;
};

struct s a[0];
```

If this struct were not padded, `a[1]` would have the address `(char *)a + 5`. That's unaligned, assuming `a[0]` is aligned. Therefore, the struct will typically be padded to a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. (Were `i` a `long long`, then the whole struct would be padded to a multiple of `sizeof(long long)`; try and see.)

With a single `char`, there's no need to pad because the `char` will be aligned anyway, while there are no other members that become unaligned. With a single `short`, an alignment of 2 is sufficient to keep the single member aligned, always.

(*) On some CPUs, but not Intel x86-compatible ones, unaligned access can actually crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is added to make sure that the `int` member `i` is aligned.

Assuming that your `int` is 4 bytes in size, then it will be placed on a 4 byte boundary to align it. That means that there are 3 bytes of padding after the `char`. The size of 12 is therefore quite reasonable.

Imagine if there was no padding. Then the offsets would be:

```
Member  Offset
j       0
c       4
i       5
```

If the struct was laid out this way then `i` would be mis-aligned. To place it on a 4 byte boundary, it needs to be at offset 8. Hence the 3 bytes of padding, and the total size of 12. So, the actual layout is:

```
Member    Offset
j         0
c         4
<padding> 5
i         8
```